# How to manually choose Source Branch for a Build definition using TFVC in TFS?

Tags: tfs-2015, tfvc, build-definition

In TFS 2015 I have the following structure for a Project:

ProjectA

- Scripts
- SystemA
- SystemB
- SystemC

Now let's say I have a build definition for SystemA with the following mappings:

1. `$/ProjectA/SystemA/trunk/src`
2. `$/ProjectA/SystemA/trunk/deploy`

When I build SystemA the source branch will be:

> $/ProjectA/SystemA/trunk

I will be able to see the changeset for the build **only for SystemA** (what I expect).

Now let's say I want to add a powershell script to my build definition in the Scripts folder. Here are the new mappings for SystemA's build definition:

1. `$/ProjectA/SystemA/trunk/src`
2. `$/ProjectA/SystemA/trunk/deploy`
3. `$/ProjectA/Scripts`

When I build again SystemA, the following source branch will be:

> $/ProjectA

The problem now is when I click a build done and troubleshoot the errors why the build failed, I have all the changesets from SystemA, SystemB, SystemC and Scripts.

I would like to manually set the Source Branch for the changesets to `$/ProjectA/SystemA/trunk/`, even if Scripts is outside of that scope and being used. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not able to change the Source Branch, it capture the same part in all mappings. You could consider create the Scripts folder under `$/ProjectA/SystemA`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That is what I thought. I hoped it was somehow possible to change it manually.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your mapping, instead of
`$/ProjectA/Scripts`, type
`$/ProjectA/SystemA/trunk/../../Scripts`
and it will trick it to use `$/ProjectA/SystemA/trunk` as the branch.

Unfortunately, I think this is more a bug than a feature since once saved, the path is shown as `$/ProjectA/Scripts` and that if you save again without manually setting the *backward* path again, the original situation comes back. Anyhow, it works as long as you think of setting the path each time you need to modify it.